# How can I check that element exist on canvas?

Tags: c#, canvas, selenium-webdriver

I am using Webdriver framework in C# for my GUI tests.

I have got a short code:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
Action drawAction = builder.moveToElement(signatureWebElement, x, y)  
            .clickAndHold()
            .moveByOffset(dest.x1, dest.y1)
            .moveByOffset(dest.x2, dest.y2)
            .release()
            .build();
            dragAction.perform();
```

I want to check that element exist on canvas or/and element has changed its position. For instance when I want to make a validation for each element that I remove or add such elements on canvas I can use only JavaScript? This canvas is wirrten by code AngularJS/PaperJS.

Comment: There is a good idea to use NuGet package SikuliSharp, and use try and catch. Anyone has used it before ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Sikuli, I think Sikuli4Net is a good package.

https://github.com/nvega-ms/SikuliDotNetExample

Comment: Ok, Thank You. I have got also SikuliSharp but I will compare it.